# nvidia-smi equivalent for AMD APU

Tags: monitoring, amd-graphics, amd

Is there something like `nvidia-smi` for AMD APU GPU? (I have A8-7600 APU)
`nvidia-smi` can show which processes are currently running on GPU, even Xorg/system applications, not only CUDA.

I'm using binary drivers from `firmware-amd-graphics` (Debian Stretch).
I would like to see at which frequency my GPU is running, how much of GPU memory is in use, etc.

Answer (score 8):

**rocm-smi** provides similar functionality (current temperature, fan speed, memory and compute usage etc). It is installed at `/opt/rocm/bin/rocm-smi`.

See https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROC-smi (pre ROCm 3.9) and https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/rocm_smi_lib/tree/master/python_smi_tools

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [GPUOpen](https://gpuopen.com/).

There is a number of useful libraries and tools there, among them [Radeon GPU Profiler](https://github.com/GPUOpen-Tools/Radeon-GPUProfiler/releases).